# What is the python requests equivalent of the following curl command

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

On ably.io they have an example where one can use the following curl request to publish a message to a channel:

```
curl -X POST https://rest.ably.io/channels/channelname/messages \
 -u "some_AP.aYYMcQ:VmGHauKOqo-35Zxo" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data '{ "name": "greeting", "data": "example" }'
```

The value passed to -u is an API key that has publish privileges. How does one make the same post request using Python requests library? I searched the documentation but could not find it. Note there is no password here, only the api key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Convert cURL syntax to Python, Node.js, PHP](http://curl.trillworks.com/) (does not seem to support basic authentication though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this:

```
requests.post("https://rest.ably.io/channels/channelname/messages",
    auth=('some_AP.aYYMcQ', 'VmGHauKOqo-35Zxo'), # Equivalent of -u
    json={ "name": "greeting", "data": "example" }) # Equivalent of --data
```

When you use the `json` option, `-H` is automatically set to `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: That worked great. Thank you. Does this mean that in an API key the content before the colon is a username, and that after the colon is a password? Will accept the answer soon. Would appreciate if you could clarify.

Comment: Some additional notes here on the `auth` argument: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Comment: Happen to know what the equivalent for -T is ?